# Embed icon in python script

Tags: python, icons, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

Does anybody know a way to embed an icon in a Python script such that when I create my standalone executable (using pyinstaller) I don't need to include the .ico file? I know this is possible with py2exe, but in my case I have to use Pyinstaller, as I was not successful using the former. I am using Tkinter.

I know about `iconbitmap(iconName.ico)` but that doesn't work if I wanna make a onefile executable.

Comment: Just to make it clearer: I want to change the icon of my application window (which by default has the Tk logo), not the icon of my file (which can be easily done with Pyinstaller)

Comment: Aha! After googling a bit more I found an answer on Stack Overflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7675014/404469). Does that help?

Comment: Yeah I've seen that one before. It's exactly my same problem. I just don't understand what he does there. It does look like it's the correct solution, maybe I should dig a bit more. Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Actually the function iconbitmap can only receive a filename as argument, so there needs to be a file there. You can make a [Base64](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) version of the icon (A string version) following the link, uploading the file and copying the result in your source file as a variable string. Extract it to a temporal file, finally passing that file to iconbitmap and deleting it. It's quite simple:

```
import base64
import os
from Tkinter import *
##The Base64 icon version as a string
icon = \
""" REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR BASE64 VERSION OF THE ICON
"""
icondata= base64.b64decode(icon)
## The temp file is icon.ico
tempFile= "icon.ico"
iconfile= open(tempFile,"wb")
## Extract the icon
iconfile.write(icondata)
iconfile.close()
root = Tk()
root.wm_iconbitmap(tempFile)
## Delete the tempfile
os.remove(tempFile)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked beautifully! Do you by any chance know how to change the icon in a figure window created with Matplotlib? My application has got my icon now, but when I plot the graph, the new window still has the TK logo as icon. Many thinks for your help

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about Matplotlib, but if there is not a function for changing the icon, I don't think there is a way. Doesn't wm_iconbitmap work in Matplotlib?

Answer (score 14):

You probably don't need this but somebody else might find this useful, I found you can do it without creating a file:

```
import Tkinter as tk

icon = """
    REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR BASE64 VERSION OF THE ICON
    """

root = tk.Tk()
img = tk.PhotoImage(data=icon)
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, img)
```

Comment: I actually wasn't able to get this method or Sam's method to work with an icon in Python 3.4.3 but Saulpila's method worked so I know there wasn't any error with the Base64 code.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution by ALI3N**

Follow these steps:

1. Edit your .spec file like this:

> ```
> a = Analysis(....)
> pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
> exe = EXE(pyz,
>           a.scripts,
>           a.binaries + [('your.ico', 'path_to_your.ico', 'DATA')], 
>           a.zipfiles,
>           a.datas, 
>           name=....
>        )
> ```

2. Add this to your script:

> ```
> datafile = "your.ico" 
> if not hasattr(sys, "frozen"):
>     datafile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), datafile) 
> else:  
>     datafile = os.path.join(sys.prefix, datafile)
> ```

3. Use it this way:

> ```
> root = tk.Tk()
> root.iconbitmap(default=datafile)
> ```

Because this wont work after You compile your script with Pyinstaller:

> ```
> root = tk.Tk()
> root.iconbitmap(default="path/to/your.ico")
> ```

**My Info**: python3.4,  pyinstaller3.1.1

Comment: Im getting error: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: For me, the solution was to use relative path for `path_to_your.ico` instead of absolute path and it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
from tkinter import  PhotoImage
import base64
img = """
REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR BASE64 VERSION OF THE ICON
"""
img= base64.b64decode(img)

root = Tk()
img=PhotoImage(data=img) 
root.wm_iconphoto(True, img)
```

Comment: worked for .png but not for .ico for me. Python 3.11.1, Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

```
import Tkinter as tk

icon = """
REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR BASE64 VERSION OF THE ICON
"""

root = tk.Tk() 
root.iconphoto(True, PhotoImage(data=icon))
```

Convert a .png file instead of an icon, also using utf-8 encoding with the same code above worked great for me!

Answer (score 1):

There is a easier and more efficient way to solving this issue.

Since you have:

```py
root.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
```

And since it is using the file from the same directory as the EXE file **all you have to do is copy the file and put it in the same directory as the application.**