# Add image to .spec file in Pyinstaller

Tags: python, icons, temp, pyinstaller

Does anybody know how to modify the `.spec` file created with the `Makespec.py` of Pyinstaller such that it includes an image data in the `_MEIPASS2` Temp dir? I want to be able to add an icon to my exe. I've done what's written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/7675014#7675014), but I just don't know how to add my data in the `.spec`.

I'm adding this line in the end of the `.spec` file:

```
a.datas += [('iconName.ico','DATA','C:\\Python26\\pyinstaller-1.5.1\\iconName.ico')]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is my spec file (`Collector.spec`) I used for a simple python program called `"Collector.py"`.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['Collector.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\vijay\\Python\\Collector'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)
a.datas += [('logo.png','C:\\Users\\vijay\\System\\icon\\logo.png','DATA')]
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='Collector.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=False , icon='C:\\Users\\vijay\\System\\icon\\logo.ico')
```

The line `"a.datas += .... "` just above pyz variable holds the path to png image that will be displayed on various windows of my GUI application. 
The `"icon=...."` variable set inside exe variable, holds the path to ico image that will be displayed on Windows Desktop as the Desktop Icon.

You can now use what Max has done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790741/2883164) in your main program (`Collector.py`, for me).

Here is a snippet of my script `Collector.py`, where I've made use of [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790741/2883164)'s Code:

```
path = self.resource_path("logo.png")
icon = wx.Icon(path, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
self.SetIcon(icon)
```

Now, when I run `pyinstaller Collector.spec`, I have both a Desktop Icon and an Icon for my Collector App windows.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

To add an icon to the executable, you need to use the following:

```
python Makespec.py --icon=<FILE.ICO> yourprogram.py
```

Or, you can add the following directly to `exe = EXE(...)` in the spec file

```
icon=<FILE.ICO>
```

This will add the file.ico to the executable's resources (Windows only), and it will show as the application icon. The a.datas append that you are using will add an icon to the internal resources which can be accessed inside the application via `sys._meipass`. You can use this to add an icon at the top of the main window, for example.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I was talking about the window icon, the one that appears at the top left of the executable. Sorry I was not clear enough in my description. Anyway, I solved it using the answer from this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929479/embed-icon-in-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

This line should be added between `a = Analysis(...)` and `pyz = PYZ(a.pure)` lines.