# Get syntax error executing a standlone .exe built from a .spec file with PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to compile a stand alone exe with PyInstaller following the instructions [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile), but I'm unable to include my two `.png` image files in the process.

I have added this code to my one and only script, `main.py`

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
        """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
        try:
            # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
            base_path = sys._MEIPASS
        except Exception:
            base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

        return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

And I have defined my images `background.png` and `closed.png` properly

```
background = resource_path("background.png")
close = resource_path("closed.png")
```

I create the .spec file and have added this line to it

> a.datas += [('icon.ico', 'C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\lolping\icon.ico','DATA'),
>       ('background.gif','C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\background.png','DATA'),
>       ('closed.png','C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\closed.png','DATA')],

But after building my .exe and running it I get this error:

```
File "main.spec", line 12
    a.datas += [('background.png', 'C:\\Deskop\\background.png','DATA',
    ('closed.png', 'C:\\Desktop\\closed.png','DATA')],
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use double backslash \  instead of just using one in

```
a.datas+= [('icon.ico', 'C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\lolping\icon.ico','DATA'), ('background.gif','C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\background.png','DATA'), ('closed.png','C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\closed.png','DATA')],
```

I believe that you might be required to write two in order for python to understand that your typing backslash. In the link below double backslash is used, so I believe the answer to your problem lies in not using double backslash but only one. I.e write

```
 a.datas+= [('icon.ico', 'C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\lolping\\icon.ico','DATA'), ('background.gif','C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\background.png','DATA'), ('closed.png','C:\\Users\\Michael\\Desktop\\closed.png','DATA')],
```

[Add image to .spec file in Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946760/add-image-to-spec-file-in-pyinstaller)