# Add .c and .h file in pyinstaller 2.0 not working

Tags: python, pyinstaller

As i took the reference from [Embed icon in python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929479/embed-icon-in-python-script) @ali3n-w0r1d answer.

I added icon file and it's perfectly fine for me, but I want to add example.c and example.h files. So what are the changes I need to add in .spec file and my python script.

Comment: Please post your spec file

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem. so this is my .spec file. I put my example_doxigen.c
and example_doxigen.h and logo.ico file in my directory where python file stored.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis([os.path.join(HOMEPATH,'doxygen_skeleton.py')],
         pathex=['E:\\pyinstaller-2.0\\pyinstaller-2.0', 'E:\\pyinstaller-2.0\\pyinstaller-2.0\\utils'],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=None)
a.datas += [ ('logo.ico', 'E:\\pyinstaller-2.0\\pyinstaller-2.0\\logo.ico', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [ ('example_doxigen.c', 'E:\\pyinstaller-2.0\\pyinstaller-2.0\\example_doxigen.c', 'DATA')]
a.datas += [ ('example_doxigen.h', 'E:\\pyinstaller-2.0\\pyinstaller-2.0\\example_doxigen.h', 'DATA')]
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name=os.path.join('dist', 'doxygen_skeleton.exe'),
      debug=False,
      strip=None,
      upx=True,
      console=False , icon='E:\\pyinstaller-2.0\\pyinstaller-2.0\\logo.ico')
```