# Python tkinter iconbitmap, onefile and add-data for exe

Tags: tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

I am trying to change the default feather icon in tkinter to a personalized icon. I have the icon file and python file in the same folder.
While building the exe using pyinstaller, I use add-data too. I use the following command in command prompt:

pyinstaller --add-data "full_path_and filename_of_icon_file;," -i "full_path_and filename_of_icon_file" scriptname.py

This seems to work because the 'dist' folder contains the .ico file.

If I use the OneFile argument:
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "full_path_and filename_of_icon_file;," -i "full_path_and filename_of_icon_file" scriptname.py

...the dist folder contains just the exe and does not seem to find the .ico file and I get a tkinter.TclError: bitmap "full_path_and filename_of_icon_file" not defined.

In my script, while defining the icon file path, I use os.getcwd + os.path.join to get the current directory of the exe file and the filename of the ico file (assuming that add-data would have added my ico file to the exe). But apparently this is not working.

Can someone please guide me? Ultimately I cannot hardcode the .ico filepath in my script because I don't wish to distribute an exe file plus an .ico file to others; but I just want to distribute the .exe file.

Following is my sample code:

```
import tkinter as tk

OptionList = [
"Aries",
"Cancer"
] 

import sys, os

exe_path = os.getcwd()
ico_file = 'PSI_logo.ico'    # or use any .ico file here

ico_path = os.path.join(exe_path, ico_file)  # dynamically generating ico path

app = tk.Tk()

app.iconbitmap(ico_path)   # dynamically generated path
app.resizable(0,0)
app.geometry('100x200')

variable = tk.StringVar(app)
variable.set("")

opt = tk.OptionMenu(app, variable, *OptionList)
opt.config(width=90, font=('Helvetica', 12))
opt.pack()

def printselection():
    print(variable.get())
    variable.set("")

mybutton = tk.Button(app, text = 'Click', command = printselection)
mybutton.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929479/embed-icon-in-python-script This post answered my question.

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me!